# which of the following sequences $\{f_n\}\in C[0,1]$ must contain a uniformly convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Could anyone tell me which of the following sequences $\{f_n\}\in C[0,1]$  must contain a uniformly convergent subsequence?

1. $|f_n(t)|\le 3\forall t\in [0,1],\forall n$
2. $f_n\in C^1[0,1],|f_n(t)|\le 3,|f_n'(t)|\le 5\forall t\in [0,1], \forall n$
3. $f_n\in C^1[0,1],\int_{0}^{1}|f_n(t)|dt\le 1, \forall n$

I am totally confused here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [Arzela-Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem), the answer 2. A sequence of functions in $C[a,b]$ has uniformly convergence subsequence iff it's uniformly bounded and equicontinuous.

Counterexamples for 1,3 are sequence of functions whose graphs is a triangle which has 1 at 0, and has increasing slope.